# Query Builder for Result Source not working in Central Admin

Tags: search, 2013, result-source

I'm trying out Result Sources at the Search Service Application level (i.e. within Central Admin). When I create a new source I can click the link to Launch Query Builder, but the Search Result Preview panel gives the following error:

```
The Search display templates are not present on this site collection. To add them, you
need to activate the "Search Server Web Parts and Templates" feature on the Site
Collection Features page.

Correlation ID: 94b6249c-d255-602d-b77b-757efe4b3071

Display Error: The display template had an error. You can correct it by fixing the 
template or by changing the display template used in either the Web Part properties or 
Result Types.

Template '~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display 
Templates/System/Control_QueryBuilderPreview.js' not found or has syntax errors. 
(LoadTemplate: )
```

This is Central Admin, and when I go to Site Settings, there is no "Site Collection Features " link, and in the "Site Features" there is no "Search Server Web Parts and Templates" feature.

Any ideas how I can get the query builder working again?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this... Open up the SharePoint 2013 Management Shell as Administrator and run the following command:

```
Enable-SPFeature SearchWebParts -url http://<central admin url>
```

Comment: Enable-SPFeature SearchWebParts -url http://<central admin url> for me worked... Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to enable this for the web application. I was getting the same error when I did it for CA.

`Enable-SPFeature SearchWebParts -url http://sales.portal.net` worked for me.